Azure Video Indexer Account type
From the pricing page of Azure Video Indexer we have

Basic Audio Indexing Analysis
Standard Audio Indexing Analysis
Advanced Audio Indexing Analysis
Basic Video Indexing Analysis
Standard Video Indexing Analysis
Advanced Video Indexing Analysis

From the Azure Portal or from the Video Indexer portal how can we change this config? And also how could we verify what is the existing account type we have?

Indexing analysis option can be chosen when you are uploading the file in Azure AI Video Indexer page. See following picture.

For API usage, you can use indexingPreset when uploading, see API documentation for Upload
About the account type: There are 2 account types, Free trial and Paid unlimited. This can been seen in the upper right corner of Azure AI Video Indexer Pages, see picture for details (me using trial account)


Great, this is useful! And how about uploading through the VI APIs. Do we have anything similar on the API level too?

Yes, you can use the indexingPreset-parameter with Upload-Video -operation. I appended this to my answer.
